# Removing TextBoxes created Dynamically on Button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have tried creating textboxes dynamically using lists. All i need now is, how can i reset all text boxes that i have created by hitting a reset button.

The following is my code:

```
public void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

    List<TextBox> inputTextBoxes;
    inputTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        Label labelInput = new Label();
        TextBox textBoxNewInput = new TextBox();

        labelInput.Text = "Activity No: " + i;
        labelInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, textBox2.Bottom + (i * 40));
        labelInput.AutoSize = true;

        textBoxNewInput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(labelInput.Width+60, labelInput.Top - 3);

        inputTextBoxes.Add(textBoxNewInput);

        this.Controls.Add(labelInput);
        this.Controls.Add(textBoxNewInput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the following line outside the event handler function (outside the function but inside the class)

> `List<TextBox> inputTextBoxes;`

Then on the reset button click

> `private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>    {
>        foreach(TextBox txt in inputTextBoxes)
>        {
>            this.Controls.Remove(txt);
>        }
>        inputTextBoxes.Clear();
>    }`

**Edit: Corrected the class type in foreach loop (from Button to TextBox)**

Comment: If you guys see the title of OP's question, he is asking to Remove the buttons, not clearing them. :)

The List is cleared only after removing the button controls from the form (foreach.....) this.Controls.Remove(btn). The list is cleared so that the next time user clicks on the button, only new buttons created (during that execution) are present in the list.

Comment: In a hurry, I typed Button instead TextBox. Did that correction. I would appreciated if those who downwoted this answer could please upvote it.

Comment: @GrantWinney: How can you ensure that the textbox you are accessing (removing from the controls collection) is the one that was added dynamically, and is not any other static textbox. For that reason only, you should have the list of textboxes that were added dynamically. Also, (when list is at class level) not clearing the List will not cause any exception or error, but the loop will run for older textboxes which are not there in the controls collection. Also, as these textboxes are still referenced by that 'List' they will not be garbage collected till the form closes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
 private void resetButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i <= inputTextBoxes.Length; i++)
     {
         inputTextBoxes[i].Text = "";
     }
 }
```

And you should declare inputTextBoxes is a class member which is same class' of buttons.